# Xamarin Forms - Camera & Design

Tags: camera, xamarin.forms

I'm looking from a couple of hours now about "How to design my app around my camera view"

So, I searched about how to use the camera and the [Xamarin XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera) and the [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) are the ones that shows up the more.

However, when I'm looking at them, also when I'm looking at [Moments](https://github.com/pierceboggan/Moments), I can't find the way or understand how can we use the camera as an XAML component, to be able to design on the live view of the camera?

I'm not coding with an MVVM logic but with a MVC logic, so maybe that why I don't get it, I don't know.

Comment: if you want to create custom camera UI it probably needs to be done with custom renderer.  Search on "camera overlay" for each platform

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view renderer for your camera, so you just have to add the view in your XAML, and you can add the design you want in your same XAML.
Take a look on this: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/

Comment: I tried ths idea https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage/ but no success, it doesn't work.... I also tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui but it's just the same as the standard UI, and I can't redesign it.. What I try to achieve is to get the viewof my camera/webcam as a background, like I put an image as background and fill it witht he stream of the camera/webcam. For the rest (taking photo/video), I'll manage by myself